# can i check connection without request and reply in real time

Tags: python, request, connection, snmp, reply

as stated above, i want to check any connection between 2 device or more, i want to check their connectivity, but i do not want to use any thing that require request and reply, i know that you can use Simple Network Management Protocol trap, but Simple Network Management Protocol trap still need to add 1 more device in between, and that device will still use ping request and reply, is there something that i could do? to detect the connection, through some protocol, i had try Control Protocol and ping, but both require request and reply.

thank you

Comment: Ping is a function that tests the connection between two devices. The method of testing a connection is trying it to see if it works. You want to test the connection without testing it?

Comment: yes if it can, but just the 3 way handshake is okay, im afraid that if the server do so much ping, lets say 5000 device and 1 server, and server always ping constanly, im afraid the server would be broken, and can get flooding. @AlistairCarscadden

Comment: Please look at this [article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Keepalive) on keepalive messages. As far as I know the only way to know if a connection is active is to test it.

Comment: thanks for your help @AlistairCarscadden